# If we want single key for multiple values

Tags: java, collections

If we have input file which contains the pair of state and city, there can be multiple cities which belongs to same state. What we have to do is we have to make that single state as key and the cities which belongs to that state as value.

For example, I am reading the following data from a file:

```
Maharashtra - Pune
Madhyapradesh - Bhopal
Maharashtra - Mumbai
Maharashtra - Nagpur
```

Here Maharashtra will become a key, with Pune, Mumbai and Nagpur  becoming values. What I did is first I split The data into state and city. I am now trying to store the states in a list and then check the list but I am stuck.

How can I make the Maharashtra as key and Pune, Mumbai and Nagpur as its respective values? Like this:

```
Maharashtra- Pune, Mumbai, Nagpur.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public class DataManagerImpl implements DataManager {

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> populateCityDataMap(String fileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list=null;
        String nameAndRollNumber=null;
        String[]  nameAndRollNumbers =null;
        String State=null;  
        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Participant_Workspace\\Q4\\CityStateLocator\\StateCityDetails.txt"));  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            nameAndRollNumber = s.nextLine();
            nameAndRollNumbers = nameAndRollNumber.split("-");
            State = nameAndRollNumbers[0];
            String City=nameAndRollNumbers[1];
            /*System.out.println(valSetOne);
            map.put(State,valSetOne);*/
            System.out.println(State+" "+City);
            list.add(State);    
        }
        /*Iterator<String> CrunchifyIterator = list.iterator();
        while (CrunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(CrunchifyIterator.next());
            }*/
        System.out.println(list);
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Key can't be same, it just over-rides. i suggest you to use a `MultiMap`

Comment: I dont have any idea about multimap. any suggestions?

Comment: You got your answer. @SMA's method works.

Comment: Java provides a [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) therefore, but you can also use a collection as value object for a certain key as showcased by @SMA

Answer (score 2):

You need something like map with key as state (which is a String) and value as list of cities (i.e. list of strings). So your data structure should be something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map ...
List<String> cities = map.get(state);
if (cities == null) {
     cities = new ArrayList<String>();
     map.put(state, cities);
}
cities.add(city);
```

Comment: But how does it assigns multiple cities to one state?

Comment: By maintaining list of cities. So one state i.e. Maharashtra as key and list of cities associated with it like Pune, Mumbai etc. Try it out to get more clarity.

Comment: I mean have can I then iterate through list

Comment: Yes why not. Try it out. `for (String city : cities) {..}`

Comment: Your code works well but if one of the state is having 3 cities, it is printing it thrice i.e [mumbai pune nagpur]*3 . what if i want to print it just once

Comment: @Sagar Can you update your question with the latest code you are using?

Comment: @Hindol code given by SMA works fine but as i said if one of the state has 3 cities, it is printing is thrice i.e [mumbai] then [mumbai, pune] and then [mumbai,pune,nagpur] what i wanted is to just print[mumbai,pune,nagpur] only once

Comment: @Sagar Move the print method call outside the loop? As I said in my last comment, it is difficult to understand what you are doing if you don't show us the updated code.

Comment: while (s.hasNext()) {

    nameAndRollNumber = s.nextLine();
      nameAndRollNumbers = nameAndRollNumber.split("-");
    State = nameAndRollNumbers[0];
   String City=nameAndRollNumbers[1];
  
   cities = map.get(State);
   if (cities == null) {
        cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(State, cities);
   }
   cities.add(City);
   
  }
   
  System.out.println(cities);
  return null;  if i am printing like this then it gives output only for one state

Comment: and when i am printing it like this while (s.hasNext()) {

    nameAndRollNumber = s.nextLine();
      nameAndRollNumbers = nameAndRollNumber.split("-");
    State = nameAndRollNumbers[0];
   String City=nameAndRollNumbers[1];
  
   cities = map.get(State);
   if (cities == null) {
        cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(State, cities);
   }
   cities.add(City);
   System.out.println(cities);
  }
   
  
  return null; then it is printing it 3 times if state has 3 cities